# users & roles both are different entites in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm working on one project for that i need solution for users & roles both are different entities.

**user entity**

```
user
id
fname
lname
email
```

**role entity**

```
roles
id
roles
```

**user_roles entity**

```
id
user_id
role_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create Role class which implements RoleInterface, and add it to your User class with ManyToMany relationship, and return the array of roles in your getRoles() method, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ManyToMany relationship as it is documented [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). In this case you only need two entities: `user` and `role`, everything else is managed with doctrine. Keep in mind that in database you still need 3 tables (`user`, `role` and `user_role`).

Example:

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an exemple of my getRoles function in my User entities:

```
    /**
     * Returns the user roles.
     *
     * @return array The roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $roles = $this->roles;

        foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
            $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
        }

        foreach ($this->getUserApplicationsPermissions() as $uap) {
            if (
                $uap->getPermanent() ||
                ($uap->getStartDate() < $now && !$uap->getEndDate()) ||
                ($uap->getStartDate() < $now && $uap->getEndDate() > $now)
            ) {
                $roles = array_merge($roles, array($uap->getApplicationPermission()->getLibelle()));
            }
        }

        // we need to make sure to have at least one role
        $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

        return array_unique($roles);
    }
```

My goal was to handle fos user roles + homemade system of role, with a period of activation or a permanent checkbox.